# Retrieving value from a textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to retrieve value from a textbox dynamically.

This code isn't working.

```
For i = 1 To TotalSheets

    ReqValue = ValidationForm.Frame6.ReportName(i).Value


Next
```

But this code does,

```
ReqValue = ValidationForm.Frame6.ReportName1.Value
```

I need to get the values dynamically through a loop.

Comment: What is your `ValidationForm`? A `UserForm` or something hand crafted using `Form controls` and / or `ActiveX controls`?

Comment: @AlexP It's an userform but those textboxes are created dynamically using vba code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reportname(i) refers to an array.

Instead, you have to concatenate the name of your control:

```
ValidationForm.Frame6.Controls(“ReportName” & i).Value
```